# script to search file in the directory recursively based on mime type

Tags: bash

I have samba share directory on centos 6 box, and I just want to make sure that all files in the share directory must be windows executable file (.exe),
Is there a way to search all directory on samba share based on they mimetype after that keep 'application/x-dosexec' mime type files and delete the rest.

I tried

```
for i in /mnt/storage/SAMBA/*
do
    [ x"$(file --mime -b "$i")" != application/x-dosexec ] && echo rm "$i"
done
```

but they don't search recursively

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`, the option `-type f` will limit the search to just files:

```
find /mnt/storage/SAMBA/ -type f | while read i ; do ... ; done
```

Please note that you forgot the `x` in your comparison. It needs to be `xapplication/x-dosexec`, or you will delete all files.

Comment: **bold**find /mnt/storage/SAMBA/ -type f | while read i;
    do
      [ x"$(file --mime-type -b "$i")" != "application/octet-stream" ] && echo rm "$i";
    done**bold** 
The result of above script:
rm /mnt/storage/SAMBA/exe/9000EastAsia_PBr5.0.0_rel1137_PL5.2.0.64_A5.0.0.exe
rm /mnt/storage/SAMBA/video/KARA-Nobody 1080HD (HD).mp4
rm /mnt/storage/SAMBA/mp3/Peter Cetera_Have You Ever Been In Love.mp3

Result of file command:
file --mime-type -b /mnt/storage/SAMBA/exe/9000EastAsia_PBr5.0.0_rel1137_PL5.2.0.64_A5.0.0.exe
application/octet-stream

Comment: Again: Please note that you forgot the "x" in your comparison. It needs to be `xapplication/x-dosexec`, or you will delete all files.